# python calculator with two float numbers as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a menu driven program using functions to make a calculator having the following operations: Add, Subtract, Multiply and Divide.

1. Define four functions, with two float numbers as parameters and
   calculate the answer. The function need not return any value as we
   can directly print the answer from there.
2. Create a menu using the print command with the respective options
   and take an input choice from the user.
3. Using if/elif statements for cases and call the appropriate
   functions.
4. Give the user an option to restart the calculator. To implement
   this, put the entire code in a while loop with the condition that
   the input from user should be, 'y' or 'Y'.

Can someone please help me with the code?

Comment: where is your code? what have you done till now?

Comment: For us to help with your code, you need to post some code for us to help you with

Comment: It looks like your asking for someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this code may help you

```
def add(a,b):
    print(a+b)
def subract(a,b):
    print(a-b)
def multipy(a,b):
    print(a*b)
def divide(a,b):
    print(a/b)
ch="y"
while ch=="y" or ch=="Y":
    x = float(input("first number : "))
    y = float(input("second number: "))
    print(".....MENU.......\n 1.Add\n 2.Subtract\n 3.Multiply\n 4.Divide\n")
    op=int(input("Enter your choice : "))
    if op==1:
        add(x,y)
    elif op==2:
        subract(x,y)
    elif op==3:
        multipy(x,y)
    elif op==4:
        divide(x,y)
    else: print("invalid Choice")
    ch=input("Do you want to continue?(Y/y) : ")
```

you may get output as:

```
    first number : 10
second number: 20
.....MENU.......
 1.Add
 2.Subtract
 3.Multiply
 4.Divide

Enter your choice : 1
30.0
Do you want to continue?(Y/y) : y
first number : 20.7
second number: 13.2
.....MENU.......
 1.Add
 2.Subtract
 3.Multiply
 4.Divide

Enter your choice : 2
7.5
Do you want to continue?(Y/y) : y
first number : 3.6
second number: 7.9
.....MENU.......
 1.Add
 2.Subtract
 3.Multiply
 4.Divide

Enter your choice : 3
28.44
Do you want to continue?(Y/y) : y
first number : 45
second number: 7
.....MENU.......
 1.Add
 2.Subtract
 3.Multiply
 4.Divide

Enter your choice : 4
6.428571428571429
Do you want to continue?(Y/y) : n

Process finished with exit code 0
```

this is a simple basic problem ...
First you have to try your own code then if you get any error while solving. You have to ask Don't just directly post your question..

Comment: You should not answer questions that are clearly off-topic. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/

Comment: Ok ..I am new to such kind .Thanks for making me aware of that @mpf82