# calculator program in python3 with help of classes and objects, not able to call the class and defined functions

Tags: python

I was studying classes and objects and trying to make mini program of calculator but the program is giving the TypeError and few more. I am not sure where is the mistake. I am posting my code here and am running it on atom.

```
class calculator:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.num1 = a
        self.num2 = b
    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b
    def subtract(self):
        return self.a - self.b
    def multiply(self):
        return self.a * self.b
    def divide(self):
        return self.a / self.b

    print("which function do you want to perform: ")
    print("1: Add")
    print("2: Subtract")
    print("3: Multiply")
    print("4: Divide")
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    switcher = {1: lambda: add(),
                2: lambda: subtract(), 
                3: lambda: multiply(), 
                4: lambda: divide() }
    func = switcher.get(choice)
    return func()


a = int(input("Enter a value: "))
b = int(input("Enter another value: "))
funct = calculator(a,b)
print(calculator.funct(a,b))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `return func()` on line 25 ?

Comment: Please include the complete error traceback in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744934/python-calculator-with-two-float-numbers-as-parameters?rq=1. It strikes me why `input()` is such a popular call in these tasks, it think it distracts attention from what a common use of interpreted language would normally be.

Answer (score -1):

There were quite a few errors. I tried to make as few changes as possible to get your code running.

```
class calculator:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.num1 = a
        self.num2 = b
    def add(self):
        return self.num1 + self.num2
    def subtract(self):
        return self.num1 - self.num2
    def multiply(self):
        return self.num1 * self.num2
    def divide(self):
        return self.num1 / self.num2
    def start(self):
        print("which function do you want to perform: ")
        print("1: Add")
        print("2: Subtract")
        print("3: Multiply")
        print("4: Divide")
        choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
        switcher = {1: self.add(),
                2: self.subtract(), 
                3: self.multiply(), 
                4: self.divide() }
        func = switcher.get(choice)
        return func

a = int(input("Enter a value: "))
b = int(input("Enter another value: "))
funct = calculator(a,b)
print(funct.start())
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vedant but the above code is also giving error, there is some problem in dictionary. the error is "AttributeError: 'calculator' object has no attribute 'add'"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers wait what's wrong with the indent?
edit: Nevermind. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Comment: @BhardwajChitra sorry I had made a mistake during pasting the code and screwed up the indentation. Should work now